# Align text on top of image using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.container{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
position:relative;
}
.text{
         position:absolute;
left:0;   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" />
  <div class="text">
  <p>
  some text here to be vertical aligned on the left where the image starts;
  </p>
  
  </div>

</div>
```

I would want that text to be on top of the image, centered vertically, on the left. Is there any other solution except of using:

```
position:absolute;
left:0;
```

I feel that it should be possible doing it with some flex attributes.

Thanks!

Comment: As a note: Try to use HTML and CSS semantically. If you need something that you would describe as a "layer", then `position: absolute` is probably your best choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/800/" />
  <div class="text">
    <p>
    some text here to be vertical aligned on the left where the image starts;
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I did:

1. Make a container the size of the image: simply put the `img` alone in a div
2. Make the above container a *positioning context*: `position: relative`
3. Create a container for aligning stuff in it, the size of its positioning context: `position: absolute` and all edges on `0`
4. Center vertically: `display: flex` plus `align-items: center`

Of course, there are other lots of ways to achieve the same effect (even completely avoiding position absolute), but I would recommend using positioning in this situation.

Comment: But were is the text here. text is not displaying here it will disrepair once image load.

Answer (score 0):

was struggling with this. Played with position with bad results until it hit me.
Just flex-direction: column (or column-reverse if necessary)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).